# Historical puzzle

Tags: history

We have three facts.

1. In reality, there are 13. But in Germany, there are 12.
2. One is Russian, one is French.
3. The thing they've created is spread all around the world.

What is it?

Edit: One more hint. People sometimes thought these two are only one person. (French and Russian)

Edit 2: Fourth one has a Sultan.

Answer (score 8):

Are they:

> The countries which signed the first Geneva Convention? Originally, 12 states signed it, then the United Kingdom of Norway and Sweden signed it later that year, making 13. Prussia was one of the signatories, so "But in Germany, there are 12" could be referring to the eventual dissolution of Prussia into Germany in 1918.

Second Clue:

> The Second French Empire signed the conventions, and parts of Prussia would eventually be incorporated into the Soviet Union.

Third Clue:

> The Geneva Conventions are pretty ubiquitous in global politics and wartime law.

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess.

> the 13 saints are being referred here.

As.

> they are supposed to spread Christianity (religion)around the world and two of them are from the countries mentioned(though I am not sure of them) and 12 from Germany could be a stretch here.

Comment: Welcome back! Haven't seen you in some months ;)